# SFX Request and a Community Project: A Sound Effect Remembering MH17

Tags: discussion

I'm sure most of you would have heard of this tragedy so I'll just get to the point. I'm trying to add a plane flyby to all my projects on hand as a tribute of sorts to the lives lost on this flight and I was also wondering if others would want to do the same. I feel particularly strongly about this incident and out of frustration of not being able to help, the least I think I can do is perhaps remember the friends of my friends through this little project. Its also a design challenge I reckon, to be able to place a plane flying by in all sorts of films.

I've got SFX of plane flybys but they are all from stock libraries so I can't freely share them, but if someone had a good recording of a plane flying overhead that I can share with someone else who wanted to do this with me then that would be greatly appreciated.

If any of you have any ideas of other platforms where I should try to take this to, do chime in.

**Update**

Does anyone with a better suggestion for another sound effect that we can use instead of a flyby, as the reference could be interpreted as a wrongly and it may be a bad reminder to some and thus offensive? I wanted something simple and easy to associate when I thought of doing this but the feedback I've been getting so far has been mixed.

Comment: Great idea Takuya!

Comment: thanks @ArnoudTraa. I hope it doesn't stay an idea and become something more. I've asked some friends to help with the recording but if anyone already has one and is willing to use it for this purpose, that'll be great too. Ultimately, it would be a great thing to have a list of 298 titles of films, tv shows, ads, etc where this SFX is used.

If anyone is interested in getting involved in this, do drop me an email. I know we are all busy so many hands will make the work light.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. Do you mean you want to use one particular SFX that we'll agree on to be added to our projects?

Comment: Hey Ariff, yes 1 SFX is what I'm after. I think if we all used 1 SFX then it'll be a more recognizable consistency in this little effort. Unfortunately I don't think there's the luxury of letting everyone choose the recording so I will use my own discretion. I'll post a link update to this as soon as I sort through the recordings that I have gotten. More details coming soon.

Comment: @AJ Henderson Sure and I did want to change the header and ask for suggestions on what other sfx did other ppl think that we could possibly use. I didn't think it through but it has dawned upon me that it might be rather insensitive as the sound may be a bad memory for them. Anyone with other ideas?

Comment: @AJ Henderson in hindsight, can you move it back to the main page. The meta site seems more fitted for moderator typed questions regarding the function and running of the forum. I think my question belongs to where the greater public is able to view more easily. I doubt many people actually get onto the meta site.